# how to create an UIImage that represent a radial portion of an UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimage

given an image below and a percentage say 25%. How can I generate another UIImage that represent 25% of the radial portion of the given image? Any help is greatly appreciated.

input
[image: input image]
output
[image: output image]

```
- (UIImage *)radialPortion:(float)percent image:(UIImage *)image;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UIImage *)radialPortion:(float)percent image:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGSize size = image.size;
    CGRect rect = {CGPointZero,size};
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGFloat radius = MAX(size.width, size.height)/2;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
    [path moveToPoint:center];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x, center.y-radius)];
    [path addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:-M_PI_2+M_PI*2*percent clockwise:1];
    [path closePath];
    [path addClip];
    [image drawInRect:rect];
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
}
```

Note:the code just work for the sample image,may not work for other image.

Comment: I have change the answer.Sorry for missing your intension before.